# Visual Studio 2012 opens Sharepoint 2013 page in login window

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sharepoint-2013

When I am trying do deploy/debug etc. my hosted app :

[image]

I am writing good credenials, and then something strange happen what happen only on one machine (sad to say it's only mine).

After putting **sign in** button (keep me signed checked/uncheced 100 times) it's would not login, but open sharepoint 2013 site in this window:

[image]

What I did:

1. reinstall visual studio
2. update visual studio
3. restart computers
4. clear cookies/catche etc.

Solved accidentally by installing CKSdev tools but only for one run...

Comment: you are saying that it wont authenticate you? Your username on top of sharepoint site menu indicates that you are logged in? It is not clear from your question what actual problem/issue is.

Comment: ye it log into site , but it should after putting "sign in" button close this windows and log project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one and only solution was reinstaling the windows, i didn find any other solution

edit:
After the newest updates this problem is solved

Answer (score 1):

It once happened to me that while it was a debug version all credentials were always rejected. I still don't really know why (it was a big project, not fully made by myself), but as a temporary solution you may try hardcoding your credentials. It's not perfect, but it may be working ;)

Comment: bad to say but temporary solution is not what i am looking for, but thx for your effort